# Outlook mobile add-in conversion

Tags: outlook, vsto, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

is it posible to simply convert the Outlook add-in to Android & IOS verion of Outlook? The add-in is programmed in C#.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. VSTO add-ins can not be easily converted to web based add-ins. You need to create a new one separately. See [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) to get started quickly.